# J-Query Beginner - Issue with JQuery Paypal Shopping Cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the script below to add a Paypal Shopping Cart on my html page

```
<!-- CSS files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jPayPalCart.css" />    

<!-- Script files -->
<script src="js/jPayPalCart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Create a basic cart
        $("#myCart").PayPalCart({ business: 'yourselleremail@yourdomain.com',
            notifyURL: 'http://www.yournotifyURL.com/notify.php',
            virtual: false,             //set to true where you are selling virtual items such as downloads
            quantityupdate: true,       //set to false if you want to disable quantity updates in the cart 
            currency: 'GBP',            //set to your trading currency - see PayPal for valid options
            currencysign: '£',          //set the currency symbol
            minicartid: 'minicart',     //element to show the number of items and net value
            persitdays: 0               //set to -1 for cookie-less cart for single page of products, 
                                        // 0 (default) persits for the session, 
                                        // x (number of days) the basket will persits between visits
            });
    });
</script>
```

The problem i am facing is: I couldn't figure out how to implement the below code to my html item button to add the item to the Cart

```
$("myCart").PayPalCart('add', code, description, quantity, value, vat);
```

My Item on my html page show as

```
<div class="grid_3">        
    <div class="pricing-table">
        <div class="top">
        <img src="images/p6.jpg" alt=""><br><span class="permonth">"AIMLESS" Gloves</span>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
        $11.95
        </div>
            <ul class="specifications">
                <li>"Aimless" Logo Embroidered Gloves are touch-screen-friendly with conductive thread on the tip of the thumb and fingers.</li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        <p><a class="button" href="#">Buy Now</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would really appreciate your expertise on this subject this is my second day on this issue. If it helps any i followed the instructions on this webpage http://www.ultimateweb.co.uk/jPayPalCart/

the script is not by PayPal this is a custom JQ Shopping Cart that is designed to use Paypal as a checkout payment terminal. Shopping Cart works perfectly, however i couldn't find out how i can make my buy now html button to add item to the cart. The website that i download the script from mentioned above stated to use this line:

```
$("myCart").PayPalCart('add', code, description, quantity, value, vat);
```

to add items to my cart

Thank you for your time i really appreciate your help

when i run the console to check errors on page using Google chrome here are the errors i get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined custom.js:1
(anonymous function) custom.js:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jPayPalCart.js:223
(anonymous function) jPayPalCart.js:223
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.php:31
(anonymous function) index.php:31
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.php:47
(anonymous function) index.php:47
```

Comment: where is the documentation of Paypal ?

Comment: I am only interested in getting the JQ Command to add item to cart, everything else works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register a click-handler for the "Buy Now" link. You can also use `data-` attributes to hold the data for the item, and then use those attributes when calling the PayPalCart "add" function.

Add to your "Buy Now" link:

```
<a class="button buyNow" href="#"
    data-code="theCode"
    data-description="theDescription"
    data-quantity="1"
    data-value="theValue"
    data-vat="theVat">Buy Now</a>
```

Then add this code to register a click-handler for the "Buy Now" link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.buyNow').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $link = $(this);
            $('#myCart').PayPalCart('add',
                $link.attr('data-code'),
                $link.attr('data-description'),
                $link.attr('data-quantity'),
                $link.attr('data-value'),
                $link.attr('data-vat'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

This way you can have multiple "Buy Now" links for different items and this click-handler will work for all of them. You can place this code in the same `<script>` element that you already have if you want.

Comment: Great thank you so much, Let me try it and i will get back to you to let you know what happens

Comment: On click nothing happens :(

Comment: @Loading - Did you add the "buyNow" class to the `<a>` element like I show in my answer? That is how I am selecting the links for registering the click-handler. There are three things you should take away from this answer in addition to registering a click-handler: (1) Using a class to identify the elements, (2) Using `this` inside the click-handler along with `data-` attributes so the click-handler works for multiple elements, and (3) Calling `event.preventDefault()` in a click-handler for an `<a>` element so the browser does not navigate to the value of the `href` attribute.

Comment: I am very positive that you are right, im totally new to jQuery so any phrase takes me lot of time to research. Give me sometime to figure this out based on your comment and i will get back to you with with what i get... Again thank you for being beside me on this

Comment: I regret to tell you i still couldn't do it :( here is the link to my index file http://ge.tt/2ijA8wF1/v/0 the button is on line 635

Comment: @Loading - I checked your code, and there's nothing wrong with the code regarding the button. I can only assume that other code is throwing an error that prevents the code that registers the click-handler from getting executed. You should look for an error in the browser. One thing I see is that `bootstrap.js` should be included after `jquery.js`.

Comment: I have moved the bootstrap.js yet no luck, and other suggestions

Comment: @Loading - No other suggestions. You should look for errors though. If you use Firefox, you should install the Firebug add-on. If you use Chrome, type Ctrl-Shift-J to view the console and look for errors.

Comment: I will work on it and update you,  thank you so much

Comment: I have updated my post above with the errors i got using Chrome, type Ctrl-Shift-J like you suggested website is here http://goo.gl/hNdMBu

Comment: @Loading - Your code looks different now. Most importantly, you need to move the `<script>` elements that load the libraries so they are above the `<script>` elements with the code in them. Also move the loading of the `custom.js` file down. It should probably be the last library loaded. Order is important for the `<script>` elements.

Comment: Ok so i arranged everything in order and most of the errors are gone, and cart is working, thank you John i need to celebrate now

Comment: @Loading - I would think you'd be too tired to celebrate. Your profile says you're in Ohio. You must have been up late last night and back at it early today.

Comment: I slept at 4 am and woke up at 7am, I had to fix this issue for a client deadline is tomorrow and i thank you for the help